# Fragment retrieved from FragmentManager sometimes has its RecyclerView Adapter set to null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my application I have one `Fragment` which is responsible for displaying a list of news items. It takes a `String` parameter which determines which url to pull data from.

I set the `Fragment` with this code:

```
private void setFragment(String pageToLoad, NewsFeedFragment newsFeedFragment) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(newsFeedFragment == null) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, NewsFeedFragment.newInstance(pageToLoad), pageToLoad);
    }
    else {
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newsFeedFragment, pageToLoad);
    }
    mPageToLoad = pageToLoad;

}
```

In my parent `Activity` I keep track of which 'page' is currently being viewed:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    if(mPageToLoad != null) {
        outState.putString("pageToLoad", mPageToLoad);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In my parent `Activity` `onCreate` method I check whether an instance of NewsFeedFragment has been created and added to the `FragmentManager` as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("pageToLoad")) {
            String pageToLoad = savedInstanceState.getString("pageToLoad");
            if(pageToLoad != null) {
                NewsFeedFragment newsFeedFragment = (NewsFeedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(pageToLoad);
                if(newsFeedFragment != null) {
                    setFragment(pageToLoad, newsFeedFragment);
                }
                else {
                    setFragment(pageToLoad, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well 99% of the time, the application resumes correctly and displays the last instance of `NewsFeedFragment` added. However, I have an issue which seems to occur randomly where the `RecyclerView` `Adapter` in `NewsFeedFragment` is sometimes `null` when the Fragment is retrieved from the `FragmentManager` using the `findFragmentByTag(pageToLoad)` method.

In `NewsFeedFragment` the `RecyclerView` `Adapter` is a `class` variable:

```
public NewsPageAdapter mNewsPageAdapter;
```

The `onActivityCreated` method of NewsFeedFragment is as follows:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(mNewsPageAdapter == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "mNewsPageAdapter is null");  // This is logged when issue occurs
    }
    if(savedInstanceState == null || mNewsPageAdapter == null) {
        new LoadFirstPageTask().execute();  // Fetches news items from web service, creates mNewsPageAdapter, and then calls setupRecyclerView() method
    }
    else {
        setupRecyclerView(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Finally, this is the NewsFeedFragment setupRecyclerView method:

```
private void setupRecyclerView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNewsPageAdapter);
}
```

From what I've described could anyone offer any insight as to why the `NewsPageAdapter` may sometimes be `null` when the `Fragment` is retrieved from The `FragmentManager`?

Thanks

Comment: where do you do `mNewsPageAdapter = ...` ?

Comment: In the `onPostExecute` method of `LoadFirstPageTask` `AsyncTask`. This task is only executed if `savedInstanceState` is `null` or `mNewsPageAdapter` is `null` in the Fragment's `onActivityCreated` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you do `new LoadFirstPageTask().execute();` and I guess that will *eventually* call setupRecyclerView?

I think you're over complicating a solution here.

You have all these conditions, business logic, and decisions made inside a volatile component (a Fragment) whose lifecycle is quite complex and not always what you'd expect; you also couple the maintenance of asynchronous data to this structure, and this is having unexpected side-effects that are hard to pin point and track down.

Creating the Adapter is "cheap" compared to fetching, processing, and producing the data for said adapter.

You don't seem to mention ViewModels anywhere, are you using a viewModel? Or any other sort of pattern like a Presenter, Interactors, useCases?

`AsyncTasks` are also *Deprecated* and while I don't advocate to run to the "refactor" hill every time a class is deprecated, I think you could get a better and more stable, testable, and readable solution if you abstract that AsyncTask into a coroutine (all managed by your ViewModel for example).

To put in other terms, your Fragment and Activity shouldn't have to deal with the logic regarding "do I need to load this data or not"; this is someone else's responsibility.

#### About *your* code.

Ok, now that I've ranted about how you're doing things, let's dig deeper into your existing Java code.

> the RecyclerView Adapter in NewsFeedFragment is sometimes null when the Fragment is retrieved from the FragmentManager using the findFragmentByTag(pageToLoad) method.

Whenever we see "sometimes" in a crash, the 1st suspect should be timing/threading. Synchronous code can fail, but it's often orders of magnitude more predictable than Asynchronous code.

If it's "sometimes" null, then the task that is in charge of changing this behavior is not always ready by the time it's needed; or the condition needed for this task to run, is not always what you expect by the time it's checked, and so on, and so forth.

Start by re-architecting your idea into a separate component.

Have the Fragment create its adapter (can be empty of data) as soon as possible, regardless of whether there's data or not.

Have the fragment ask *another component* for the data. And when the data is available, send it to the Fragment who will in turn set it in the adapter. If the data is already there by the time you ask for it (because you "cached" it), you won't have to wait.

I'd also store the "last viewed page" in the same component, so you don't need to save the state and pass it alongside to a fragment. Rather the fragment asks for "the current data" and the *component* already knows what it is.

All in all, it's a bit difficult to put all your pieces together because we, the readers, don't have all the code, nor your requirements that lead you to this solution.